# Prompt ---> Confirm ---> another page

Tags: javascript, prompt, confirm

I am creating a quiz-like game for my project in school. If the person wrote the right answer in the prompt box, I want the confirm box to appear after that. (If not, then alert box must appear.) I know how to do this already. But then, when you clicked "OK" at the confirm box, it must redirect to the next page.

My problem is that.. **What is the code for the confirm box that appears when the right answer was typed in the prompt box and how would it redirect to another page when I clicked "OK"?**

Help me please T^T

Comment: `window.confirm`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 var ans = prompt("Enter your answer!");

//Process Ajax Request to check answer
//Get Response from script

if(response == true){
//Redirect to next question 
window.location = 'question.php';
}else{
//Show error or handle wrong input
alert('Wrong Answer');
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (confirm("Next page") )
{
    window.location = "newlocation";
}
```